# How to send json file throw POST method and recive it on the servlet

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I'm trying to send a json object like: `{id: 1, firstName: Paul, lastName: Lambert}`

The problem is that I'm getting a NULL or wrong parameters on the json object

```
testProjectApp.factory('updateClient', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        postClient: function (clientData) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            alert(clientData.firstName);
            $http({
                url: 'UpdateClient',
                method: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(clientData)
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.reject(status);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

and in the servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    JSONObject json;
    try {
        System.out.println(request.getParameter("data"));
        json=new JSONObject(request.getReader());
        ....
```

Comment: This is not enough info to debug the problem.  Could you please post (a) The server stack trace, (b) The HTTP request contents.

Comment: I don't get an error , the system.out.println return null

Comment: First, in your angular code dont do `data: JSON.stringify(clientData)` instead just pass in your `clientData` object `data: clientData`, Angular will take care of the rest. Second in your `doPost` method the data sent isnt a request parameter. The JSON data is sent in the request body, you access it using `request.getReader()` or `request.getInputStream()` as you are currently doing when parsing the JSONObject.

Comment: @ug_ Your comment should be posted as an answer, no?

Comment: I'm still getting bad data on the json object, I've tried json=new JSONObject(request.getInputStream());

Answer (score 1):

No need to do `data: JSON.stringify(clientData)`. Angular will automatically format into JSON.

**Controller code :**

```
    function updateClient($scope, $http) {
    $scope.client = {};
    $scope.clientUpdate = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : '/UpdateClient',
            data : $scope.client
        }).success(function(data) {
           // do something if the request is success
        }).error(function(data) {
           // do something if the request is fail
        });

    }
```

**Servlet code :**

```
JSONObject jsnObjt = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("data"));
Iterator it = jsnObjt.keys(); 

while(it.hasNext())
{
    String key = it.next(); 
    Object ob = jsnObjt.get(key); 

    String user = jsnObjt.get("client");
}
```

**Sample HTML regarding your requirement :**

```
<form ng-controller="updateClient" ng-submit="clientUpdate()">
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" ng-model="client.id">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" ng-model="client.firstName"> 
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" ng-model="client.lastName">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Update</button>

</form>
```